# How to trigger Azure Build/Release Pipelines from Slack?

Tags: azure-devops, slack, cicd, chatops

Apologies if this was asked earlier, but I wanted to know if there is a way to trigger Azure DevOps pipeline by running commands in slack?

I understand Slack can be used to monitor or get notifications whenever a pipeline is started/completed with/without errors. But is there a way to send a https post request to a Azure Pipeline and trigger the build/release similar to how it is done through postman?

Is this something that can be achieved through API calls in slack or using slash commands? Please suggest, any leads would be helpful.